# Problems wth Opencv and VC++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have configured Opencv 2.4.2 with Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition. I have linked and included all files. Now when I compile any file , complier gives error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core231d.lib'".

I searched the OPENCV folder where I have extracted the files , there is no 'opencv_core231d.lib' there. How can I reslove this problem.

Comment: Why are you linking to opencv 2.3.1 libs instead of 2.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You should link with **opencv_core242d.lib** not the one you mentioned.

1. If you downloaded the source code, ensure that you ran cmake to generate the VC++ solution file and then built the solution( in both release and debug mode).
2. Check that the **opencv_core242d.lib** file is present in `<build folder>\lib\Debug`
3. Check that you have added the **OpenCV\< build folder >\lib\Debug**  path to Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile opencv before using it. Follow the simple steps [here](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/compiling-opencv-with-openni-for.html) to compile and setup a project. This tutorial is used to compile opencv with openni support (but you can skip that part).

If you search more you will find a lot of similar tutorials for compiling opencv with VC++.

Answer (score 0):

```
properties --> linked --> input
```

put :

```
opencv_calib3d220.lib
opencv_calib3d220d.lib
opencv_contrib220.lib
opencv_contrib220d.lib
opencv_core220.lib
opencv_core220d.lib
opencv_features2d220.lib
opencv_features2d220d.lib
opencv_ffmpeg220.lib
opencv_ffmpeg220d.lib
opencv_flann220.lib
opencv_flann220d.lib
opencv_gpu220.lib
opencv_gpu220d.lib
opencv_highgui220.lib
opencv_highgui220d.lib
opencv_imgproc220.lib
opencv_imgproc220d.lib
opencv_legacy220.lib
opencv_legacy220d.lib
opencv_ml220.lib
opencv_ml220d.lib
opencv_objdetect220.lib
opencv_objdetect220d.lib
opencv_ts220.lib
opencv_video220.lib
opencv_video220d.lib
```